# Is there always a minimal coloring for a graph for which one of the colors is a maximum set?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Take a graph $G$ and suppose it is $k$-chromatic. Is there always a $k$-coloring such that one of the "colors" (the independent sets that compose the coloring) will have cardinality equal to $G$'s independence number?

If not, what conditions on the graph could make this true?

Comment: Be very careful about the differences between the words maxim**um** and maxim**al**.  Maximums are unique and need not exist, maximals don't need to be unique and will always exist for finite cases.  As for the content of your question, [this related post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118143/coloring-a-graph-by-maximum-independent-set-extraction) on mathoverflow implies that the answer is no.  As for what conditions would be sufficient (*and not circular*) I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this graph:

```
O       O
 \     /
  O---O
 /     \
O       O
```

This is 2-colorable, but its independence number is 4 and there is no 2-coloring with 4 vertices of the same color.

Answer (score 0):

To repeat the argument from [this mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118143/coloring-a-graph-by-maximum-independent-set-extraction) post, consider the following graph:

[image]

The graph is in fact four-colorable:

[image]

A maximal independent set uses vertices $a,d,e,h$ and is of size four.  In fact, it is a maxim*um* independent set as well as no other independent sets of size four exist.  (*if the set of size four is not $a,d,e,h$ then it must use one of $b,c,f,g$, but if none of the other three touch the chosen vertex, the remaining three must have adjacencies themselves*)

If we were to force all four of these to have the same color however...

[image]

All members of the $K_4$ in the center must be different than red, and the graph will use five colors instead, not four.